# How do I select a column by its name? (Python & SQLite3)

Tags: python, sqlite

Currently I have the following code:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
for row in c.fetchall():
    print row[0]
    print row[1]
```

However, I changed the structure of my table and now I have to change the index values to represent this change. Is there a way to get use column names instead?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [Row Objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#row-objects) in the docs for the sqlite3 module.  If you use the `sqlite3.Row` row_factory you'll get back an object that's slightly more powerful than the normal tuples.  I imagine it has slightly higher overhead, hence not being the default behavior.

Comment: No real higher overhead according to the doc: _"Row provides both index-based and case-insensitive name-based access to columns **with almost no memory overhead**. It will probably be better than your own custom dictionary-based approach or even a db_row based solution."_ http://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory

Comment: Yeah that makes sense--I haven't looked at the code but it probably just uses `__getitem__` to map column names to their corresponding indices.

Answer (score 12):

For this reason, it is recommended to always use explicit column names when doing a `SELECT`:

```py
c.execute("SELECT color, fluffiness FROM table")
for row in c.fetchall():
    print row[0]         #  <-- is always guaranteed to be the color value
    print row[1]
```

Comment: This is a good answer too. Or some combination thereof. Though it can be a pain of you're fetching all columns of a large-ish table.